# Dispatch function in python, how does the data is saved?

Tags: python, function, oop, memory, dispatch

I'm now learning about software engineering and as a part of my studies i had to implement a dispatch function for a mutable pair type.

Here is my implementation:

```
def make_mutable_pair(*args):
    x = None
    y = None
    numargs = len(args)

    if (numargs == 1):
        x = args[0]
    elif (numargs == 2):
        x = args[0]
        y = args[1]
    elif (numargs >= 3):
        raise Exception("Too many arguements!")
    else:
        pass

    def dispatch(msg, i=None, v=None):
        if(msg == 'get'):
            return get_item(i)
        elif(msg == 'set'):
            return set_item(i,v)

    def get_item(i):
        if(i == 0):
            return x
        elif(i == 1):
            return y
        else:
            raise Exception("Wrong index!")

    def set_item(i,v):
        nonlocal x,y
        if(i == 0):
            x = v
        elif(i == 1):
            y = v
        else:
            raise Exception("Wrong index!")

    return dispatch
```

I understand everything pretty well but there is something that is against everything i know in software and coding, the 'make_mutable_pair' is basically a function, here is some test i did:

```
test = make_mutable_pair(5,10)
print('({},{})'.format(test('get',0),test('get',1)))

test('set',0,3)
test('set',1,6)

print('({},{})'.format(test('get',0),test('get',1)))
```

As expected, the output will be:

```
(5,10)
(3,6)
```

What i don't understand is how the x and y are saved...
I mean from what i know, when i'm done with a function all the data in the stack memory will be deleted, and in the next call to that function i'm starting fresh.

In this case i called the function with some data for x and y, and later i changed it, and called it again, and it's still saved...

I will love to hear some explanation about it... Thanks!

Comment: Look up [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).